# Name pgfplotstable Column within foreach loop

Tags: pgfplotstable, foreach

I recently stumbled over [`pgfplotstable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) and its ability to process table information and create new columns. To hone my skills, I tried to create a script that would calculate an exponential smoothing forecast for a timeseries for different smoothing factors.

The calculation and plotting seems to have worked just fine, but I could not manage to give each of the new columns in the table a new column name that would appear if I print out the table using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

The assignment in general seems to work (i.e. the column name is changed from its default, however, all columns end up having the same column name, when I print the table. Attached is my stripped down case:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=10cm,legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \begin{document}

    % read observed time-series
    \pgfplotstableread{
    x   y
    1   4.237485502
    2   5.593257216
    3   6.101509413
    4   5.328536597
    5   6.353556834
    6   5.84178478
    7   5.271878886
    8   6.952802431
    9   4.579257831
    10  7.742456136
    }\mytable

    % get first x-Value as forecast value for period 1
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of{\mytable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\finit}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % iterate through different levels of \alpha
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \alph in {10,20,...,50}{
        \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
            expr accum={ % in the first row, do not calculate forecast as linear combination of actual demand and forecast of last period, but just use initial value
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
                    \finit
                \else
                    (1-\alph/100)*\pgfmathaccuma+\alph/100*\prevrow{y}
                \fi
            }{\finit}
        ]{\alph}{\mytable}
        % set name for column and display style
        \pgfplotstableset{columns/\expandafter\alph/.style={column name={$ES_{\alph}$},dec sep align={c}}}
    }
    % print forecasted values
    \begin{table}
            \center
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
                    header=has colnames
            ]{\mytable}
        \caption{Results of the Exponential Smoothing Excercise (Table)}
    \end{table}

    % plot observed and forecasted timeseries
    \begin{figure}
        \center
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    legend cell align=left,legend pos=north west,
                    xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$Y$
                ]
                \addplot[only marks] table[y=y,x=x]{\mytable};
                \addlegendentry{Original Data};
                \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {10,20,...,50}{
                    \addplot +[mark=none,thin] table[y=#1,x=x]{\mytable};
                    \addlegendentry{$\alpha=\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}\%$};
                }
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Results of the Exponential Smoothing Excercise (Plot)}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

While you're at it: Do you know how I can define the values for alpha (`10,20,...,50` in my code) only once and reuse it? I am aware that this is a different question, but my first attempts did not work and these might be low hanging fruits for you ;-)

Comment: You need expanded style hence `estyle` `\pgfplotstableset{columns/\alph/.estyle={column name={$ES_{\alph}$},dec sep align={c}}}`. Also that `\expandafter` does not do anything. If you want to expand that one too, you need to start from `\pgfplotstableset` and the first brace.

Comment: Great, that worked! The `\expandafter` was a remainder of my attempts to fix the problem because I assumed it would come down to expansion, but I was not aware of the `.estyle` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close the threat here: The solution suggested by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) works perfectly!

Here is the essential part of the line of code that assigns the column name within `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`:

```
\pgfplotstableset{columns/\alph/.estyle={column name={$ES_{\alph}$}}}
```